# Google Maps API request per page/user. How to reduce the requests best?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, static, client-side

I am actually working on a web app that stores addresse and lat long data from a service like bing or openstreetmap. Now I want a google satellite map on my webpage that shows a certain amount of nearby locations. I already have the data. Just want to implement it with a layer on top of a google map. Now my question. Does my web app send an api request to google to generate the map every time the site is been refreshed? Or just once to generate it? The app will be used by lots of users so the 2500requests/per day is hardly kicking me in the ass.
It is totally fine to use the static map api. I read about 25000requests per day but it's still not enough for me. Next point I read was the "1000 static map requests per IP address per 24 hour period. This limit does not apply if you use an API key." Note. Question now: Is it possible to send the static map request client sided and show this map on a specific part of the app? I don't think a user will use more than 1000 location requests per day. This would totally fit in my concept.

Answer (score 0):

Static Maps will not solve your problem, the limit of 25000 Map-loads/24h also applies to StaticMaps, a single request to a StaticMap will count the same as a single instance of a `google.maps.Map`

[**What constitutes a 'map load' in the context of the usage limits that apply to the Maps API?**](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload)

**A single map load occurs when:**

- **a map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API (V2 or V3) when loaded by a web page or application;**
- a Street View panorama is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API (V2 or V3) by a web page or application that has not also displayed a map;
- a SWF that loads the Maps API for Flash is loaded by a web page or application; or
- **a single request is made for a map image from the Static Maps API.**
- a single request is made for a panorama image from the Street View Image API.